Including BLE ESP32 IDF component fails
I'm trying to include the BLE header into my ESP32 project,
added line
REQUIRES bt esp_common driver hal freertos log
to CMakeLists.txt as instructed by documentation
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/esp32/api-reference/bluetooth/esp_gap_ble.html
compiled with latest docker image
sudo docker run --rm -v $PWD:/project -w /project -u $UID -e HOME=/tmp espressif/idf idf.py build
but still getting
/project/main/ble_wrp.c:9:10: fatal error: esp_gap_ble_api.h: No such file or directory 9 | #include "esp_gap_ble_api.h" compilation terminated. 
Missing "esp_gap_ble_api.h" file name found in the following component(s): bt(/opt/esp/idf/components/bt/host/bluedroid/api/include/api/esp_gap_ble_api.h). Maybe one of the components needs to add the missing header directory to INCLUDE_DIRS of idf_component_register call in CMakeLists.txt.

weirdly I didn't have any problem including wifi, didn't even have to modify REQUIRES for it
#include "esp_wifi.h"

In which CMakeLists.txt did you afd this?

Into one that already contained idf_component_register( INCLUDE_DIRS SRCS  REQUIRES )
